# How to return total number of rows loaded in python from a merge statement in BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Is there a way of returning the total number of rows loaded to the destination table from a merge statement? My code always returns 0. I am assuming that this is because bigquery does not store the number of rows after the job has finished. I know that `.total_rows` works for standard SELECT queries but is it possible to do the same for INSERT/MERGE queries?

```
sql = """
merge into `{destTable}` dest 
using 
 ( select 
   column1, 
   column2
   from sampleTable  
)
source on source.column1 = dest.column1
when not matched then 
insert (column1, column2)
values (column1, column2)
"""

client = bigquery.Client()
job = client.query(sql)
result = job.result()
print(result.total_rows) # this always returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the output from num_dml_affected_rows parameter i.e print(result.num_dml_affected_rows). This should provide you the row count affected by the merge operation.

Comment: Thank you! That was bugging me. This works but rather than printing the output from job.result() it needs to be printed on the job i.e.  client.query(sql).num_dml_affected_rows.